# Create Image modal for image gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image

I'm Trying to create Image modal for image gallery,But I don't see result When Click on Image,I Don't Know where is problem

How I can fixed it?where is my Wrong?I Used this 
 link https://codepen.io/koolhaus/pen/ajwcE

My code is

```
<script>
      $(document).on('ready', function(){
       $modal = $('.modal-frame');
      $overlay = $('.modal-overlay');
      $modal.bind('webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend msAnimationEnd 
     animationend', function(e){
      if($modal.hasClass('state-leave')) {
        $modal.removeClass('state-leave');
    }
   });

  $('.close').on('click', function(){
      $overlay.removeClass('state-show');
       $modal.removeClass('state-appear').addClass('state-leave');
   });

  $('.open').on('click', function(){
       $overlay.addClass('state-show');
       $modal.removeClass('state-leave').addClass('state-appear');
     });

    });
    $("button").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            method: 'GET',
            url: './comment?media_id=' + this.id,
            success: function (data) {
                $("#comments").html(data);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

```
<div id="comments">
   <div class="modal-frame">
    <div class="modal">
            </div>
        </div>

@foreach($array as $img)

           <li style="margin:0 auto">
                <a  class="fancy-btn open">
                    <img src="{{$img['image']}}">
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

Comment: Your modal perfectly working. A pop-up "Such Modal, Much Animate!" ..

Comment: Check updated code with working, https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EvVRea
replace your image src in that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).on('ready', function() {
  $modal = $('.modal-frame');
  $overlay = $('.modal-overlay');
  $modal.bind('webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend msAnimationEnd animationend', function(e) {
    if ($modal.hasClass('state-leave')) {
      $modal.removeClass('state-leave');
    }
  });

  $('.close').on('click', function() {
    $overlay.removeClass('state-show');
    $modal.removeClass('state-appear').addClass('state-leave');
  });

  $('.open').on('click', function() {

    $overlay.addClass('state-show');
    $modal.removeClass('state-leave').addClass('state-appear');
  });

});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 22px;
  background-color: #F2E1AC;
}

.fancy-btn {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  display: block;
  min-width: 10%;
  line-height: 55px;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 10px;
  background-color: #F2594B;
  color: #FFF;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.fancy-btn:hover {
  background-color: #f46f63;
}

.modal-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #fff;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 40;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.25s ease 0s, visibility 0.35s linear;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.25s ease 0s, visibility 0.35s linear;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.25s ease, visibility 0.35s linear;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s, 0s;
  transition: opacity 0.25s ease 0s, visibility 0.35s linear;
}

.modal-overlay.state-show {
  opacity: .7;
  visibility: visible;
  -moz-transition-delay: 0s;
  -o-transition-delay: 0s;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
  transition-delay: 0s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.2s, 0s;
  -o-transition-duration: 0.2s, 0s;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s, 0s;
  transition-duration: 0.2s, 0s;
}

.modal-frame {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  z-index: 50;
  /*     display: table; */
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  -moz-box-align: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -moz-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.modal-frame.state-appear {
  visibility: visible;
}

.modal-frame.state-appear .modal-inset {
  -moz-animation: modalComeIn 0.25s ease;
  -webkit-animation: modalComeIn 0.25s ease;
  animation: modalComeIn 0.25s ease;
  visibility: visible;
  /* to keep @ final state */
}

.modal-frame.state-appear .modal-body {
  opacity: 1;
  -moz-transform: translateY(0) scale(1, 1);
  -ms-transform: translateY(0) scale(1, 1);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0) scale(1, 1);
  transform: translateY(0) scale(1, 1);
}

.modal-frame.state-leave {
  visibility: visible;
}

.modal-frame.state-leave .modal-inset {
  -moz-animation: modalHeadOut 0.35s ease 0.1s;
  -webkit-animation: modalHeadOut 0.35s ease 0.1s;
  animation: modalHeadOut 0.35s ease 0.1s;
  visibility: visible;
}

.modal-frame.state-leave .modal-body {
  opacity: 0;
  -moz-transition-delay: 0s;
  -o-transition-delay: 0s;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
  transition-delay: 0s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.35s;
  -o-transition-duration: 0.35s;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.35s;
  transition-duration: 0.35s;
  -moz-transition-timing-function: ease;
  -o-transition-timing-function: ease;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
  -moz-transform: translateY(25px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(25px);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(25px);
  transform: translateY(25px);
}

@-moz-document url-prefix() {
  .modal-frame {
    height: calc(100% - 55px);
  }
}

.modal {
  display: block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}

.modal-inset {
  position: relative;
  padding: 60px;
  background-color: white;
  min-width: 320px;
  min-height: 126px;
  margin: auto;
  visibility: hidden;
  -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.modal-inset .close {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  opacity: .4;
}

.modal-inset .close:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.modal-body {
  margin: auto;
  opacity: 0;
  -moz-transform: translateY(0) scale(0.8, 0.8);
  -ms-transform: translateY(0) scale(0.8, 0.8);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0) scale(0.8, 0.8);
  transform: translateY(0) scale(0.8, 0.8);
  -moz-transition-property: opacity, -moz-transform;
  -o-transition-property: opacity, -o-transform;
  -webkit-transition-property: opacity, -webkit-transform;
  transition-property: opacity, transform;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.25s;
  -o-transition-duration: 0.25s;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.25s;
  transition-duration: 0.25s;
  -moz-transition-delay: 0.1s;
  -o-transition-delay: 0.1s;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.1s;
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
}

.modal-body h3 {
  font-weight: 700;
  padding-bottom: 22px;
  display: block;
  color: #F2594B;
  text-align: center;
}

.modal-body p {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.modal-body .ps {
  font-size: 12px;
  opacity: .3;
}

@-webkit-keyframes modalComeIn {
  0% {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transform: scale(0.8, 0.8);
    -ms-transform: scale(0.8, 0.8);
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.8, 0.8);
    transform: scale(0.8, 0.8);
  }
  65.5% {
    -moz-transform: scale(1.03, 1.03);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.03, 1.03);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.03, 1.03);
    transform: scale(1.03, 1.03);
  }
  100% {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transform: scale(1, 1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1, 1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
    transform: scale(1, 1);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes modalComeIn {
  0% {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transform: scale(0.8, 0.8);
    -ms-transform: scale(0.8, 0.8);
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.8, 0.8);
    transform: scale(0.8, 0.8);
  }
  65.5% {
    -moz-transform: scale(1.03, 1.03);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.03, 1.03);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.03, 1.03);
    transform: scale(1.03, 1.03);
  }
  100% {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transform: scale(1, 1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1, 1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
    transform: scale(1, 1);
  }
}

@keyframes modalComeIn {
  0% {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transform: scale(0.8, 0.8);
    -ms-transform: scale(0.8, 0.8);
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.8, 0.8);
    transform: scale(0.8, 0.8);
  }
  65.5% {
    -moz-transform: scale(1.03, 1.03);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.03, 1.03);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.03, 1.03);
    transform: scale(1.03, 1.03);
  }
  100% {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transform: scale(1, 1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1, 1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
    transform: scale(1, 1);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes modalHeadOut {
  0% {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transform: translateY(0) scale(1, 1);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0) scale(1, 1);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0) scale(1, 1);
    transform: translateY(0) scale(1, 1);
  }
  100% {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transform: translateY(35px) scale(0.97, 0.97);
    -ms-transform: translateY(35px) scale(0.97, 0.97);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(35px) scale(0.97, 0.97);
    transform: translateY(35px) scale(0.97, 0.97);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes modalHeadOut {
  0% {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transform: translateY(0) scale(1, 1);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0) scale(1, 1);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0) scale(1, 1);
    transform: translateY(0) scale(1, 1);
  }
  100% {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transform: translateY(35px) scale(0.97, 0.97);
    -ms-transform: translateY(35px) scale(0.97, 0.97);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(35px) scale(0.97, 0.97);
    transform: translateY(35px) scale(0.97, 0.97);
  }
}

@keyframes modalHeadOut {
  0% {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transform: translateY(0) scale(1, 1);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0) scale(1, 1);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0) scale(1, 1);
    transform: translateY(0) scale(1, 1);
  }
  100% {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transform: translateY(35px) scale(0.97, 0.97);
    -ms-transform: translateY(35px) scale(0.97, 0.97);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(35px) scale(0.97, 0.97);
    transform: translateY(35px) scale(0.97, 0.97);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="modal-frame">
  <div class="modal">
    <div class="modal-inset">
      <div class="button close"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></div>

      <div class="modal-body">
        <h3>Hello header</h3>
        <p>body here......</p>
        <p class="ps">ps!!!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-overlay"></div>

<div id="comments">


  <li style="margin:0 auto">
    <a width="100" height="100" class="fancy-btn open"> <img alt="Image Here" />

    </a>
  </li>

</div>
```